Extending PageController from the root namespace in a SilverStripe submodule
Updating a site from SS3(!).  The page controller is:
// /app/src/controller/PageController.php
namespace {    
    // use statements          
    class PageController extends ContentController
    {

How can I extend this controller in a module eg:
// site-management/SiteManagementPage.php
class SiteManagementPage_Controller extends PageController {

I get this error:
Error: Class "PageController" not found.
I've tried various variations on location and class names.  How can i align my code so the autoloader can find PageController?  Do I need a use statement in SiteManagementPage?

When you get that error, is it in the context of a fully functioning project which has been built using composer create-project silverstripe/installer? The PageController class is part of project code (provided by silverstripe/recipe-cms which is a dependency of installer) so without a functioning project you can't expect that class to exist.
